# get_categories() returns "Uncategorised"

Tags: categories, multisite

On the front-end of my WPMU site all categories vanished and every post is marked with "Uncategorised". This is however only on the single.php and not on home.php.

The same error occurs on `get_categories()`, `wp_list_categories()` and `the_category()`.

I've tried to look in to the problem with `var_dump(get_categories())` but it like WordPress simply thinks that it should be that way.

Comment: Did you try to assign category again from admin panel?

Comment: Yeah I did. Both changing while just having one category assigned and aslo adding multiple categories. But on the front-end it still only says "Uncategorized"

Comment: Did you update your wordpress version recently? OR installed any plugin recently?

Comment: It seems like wordperss was confused about which blog it was on and pulled the category from another blog post. When i used `switch_to_blog(1)` (which that page always will be) it worked as it should, thanks anyways!

Comment: Hmm. I see...Okay.

Comment: Please answer your own question. You can then mark it as solved later on. Else the question will stay open for ages. Hint: When you try to answer your own question (which we encourage), then you'll surely learn a lot. You will also more likely get an answer by someone else or comments on your answer that may help to pin point it more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there was some kind of problem with my multisite setup which caused WordPress to fetch the categories from some other blogs posts. (Can't really tell where from actually). However by writing `switch_to_blog(1)` (which it always will be) it seemed to work as it should.